# Is it possible to export (and then import) plugins and their settings in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have several good plugins in my IDEA and now switched to new version. All settings have been exported and then imported but plugins. How can I easily move them from 11 to 12 version? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA manages plug-ins compatibility when plug-ins are [installed from the repository](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-installing-and-uninstalling-plugins-from-a-repository.html), it automatically finds the latest compatible version when downloading.

However, if you just copy version 11 compatible plug-ins to IDEA 12, it will most likely break and even not start as there were a lot of API changes and many plug-ins would require upgrading to be fully compatible with IDEA 12.

It's exactly the case why plug-ins are not automatically copied to the new version when you import the settings from the old version.

Even if a plug-in is listed as compatible, it may still not work if the maintainer didn't limit the upper compatible build number or did it incorrectly.

I would strongly recommend installing plug-ins that you need from the repository carefully checking the latest release date and compatibility information. If someting breaks and IDEA stops working, delete the incompatible plug-in manually from the [plugins directory](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181).

Considering that IDEA 12 is not even released at the moment of this writing (RC3 is available), it may take some time until all the plug-ins that you need are updated to be compatible with this version. You may want to continue using IDEA 11 version until it happens.

---

If you want to take the risk, just copy [plug-ins directory](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) from the old version to the new one, but you've been warned.

Comment: why doesn't idea try to download and install plugins itself?

Comment: @Eugen It does -- after successful launch (when all plugins are already loaded).

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot smarter something like what maven does about dependencies, just manage a xml file with installed plugins, and then in the export/import settings process just do whatever plug-in-compatibility-check idea does and download/install the compatible plugins.

Doesn't sound to hard to implement in further updates of IDEA 12.

Meanwhile, you can manage to make a list of plugins checking the old folder and downloading one by one, because making a copy of the old plug-in folder to the new most likely make idea 12 to crash...

Good Luck.

If anybody knows how to report a jira/ticket to jetbrains, point me in the right direction and I'll gladly report this as an improvement.